# How do I update Ubuntu system independent of third party apps?

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, xubuntu, dpkg

I'm trying to update my packages so that I can upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 Xubuntu via terminal.

This will install available updates for all available packages including Firefox, ones which I installed later on like opera browser, etc. This is unwanted for me.

How can I just update the core system packages alone and fast forward to upgrading my system? In other words, how to make these app updates independent from system updates?

Comment: Why would you want that? Packages have dependencies and trying to hold back packages is risky and may end breaking up the system.

Comment: @ToDo Some of the apps include installations via .deb files which could make up a huge download size. Aren't these packages supposed to work standalone? I'm not sure. I use Windows mostly, and this model of OS update seems daunting to me, when I'm now at home on a limited data plan. How come Windows update does not cause dependency issues as there are shared dlls in system32 folder?

Comment: even if you install package by downloading in .deb format it stills have dependencies. remember when you don't have dependencies that packed .deb software also install what it need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy the file from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` in that text file remove everything but not with domain ubuntu.com. And please dont forget to backup these text file because you need it later. Now run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

after update complete keep the orginal content files and its content where it was before and run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This is what you should do. But as a reminder you should have better update all packages until you are doing something strict

Answer (score 0):

The Debian model of software packages makes what you want very difficult (impossible in some circumstances, trivial in others). The concept of a "core system" is not defined in Debian. All software, whether you consider it *core* or *non-core*, uses the same package system, the same dependencies, and the same uniform versions.

That '*same versions*' requirement is often the stopper for using wrong-version packages.

- **Warning**: When you try to bypass package version requirements, you may break your system.

The concept of a "core system" IS defined in a Snap-based system like Ubuntu Core, and updates of core- and non-core snaps are unrelated...but the idea of withholding upgrades is rather anathema to Snap-based systems.